# handsontable onChange()/afterChange() parms questions

Tags: jquery-plugins, handsontable

I'm using an older version of handsontable.

It has a function called onChange(changes, source) and I've got some questions about them.

Can someone confirm changes is a comma separated String?

can someone confirm its formatted as follows:

row,column name,previous cell value, new cell value

where previous cell value is optional and may be omitted?

Can anyone tell me the possible values for source and what they mean?

Does the above information applicable to afterChange() as well?

If there is a link to some docs that explain all this - please please please include it in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find answers about afterchange/beforechange here:https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/wiki/Events

> changes is a 2D array containing information about each of the edited
>   cells [ [row, prop, oldVal, newVal], ... ].

As for the older version, I don't know